# Complicated variable content failed to get into sed

Tags: shell, sed

The first line is variable `ann` hold quite complicated value. The reason I use the second line is because I don't want to change anything in the third line `col1content`. To change replacement, I just need to change second line to other variable.

```
ann="<?php echo '<h2>'.views_get_view('frprev_ann')->get_title().'<\/h2>'; echo views_embed_view('frprev_ann'); ?>"
col1content=`echo $ann`
sed -i 's/r'$rownum'c1content/'$col1content'/g' templates/page--front.tpl.php
```

But when  above command has been run, it result in error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unterminated `s' command
```

If I change the first line to be `ann="testtext"`, everything running smoothly. And when change first line to be `ann="<?first second"`, it fails. using backslash also cannot help me.

Comment: why you do you want your code to contain `\`col1content=echo $ann\`` in the second line instead of `col1content=$ann`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/r'$rownum'c1content/'"$col1content"'/g' templates/page--front.tpl.php
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't reliably pass text to `sed` like this. In the replacement text, you need to quote `\`, `&` and the `s` delimiter (usually `/`) by adding a backslash before them. In the regex part, you need to quote `\[.*^$` and the delimiter.

In addition, you've left the value of the variable to be further expanded by the shell. **Always use double quotes around variable substitutions**, i.e. `"$foo"`, not <s>`$foo`</s>. Without double quotes, the value is interpreted as a whitespace-delimited list of glob patterns; whitespace and `\[?*` are expanded.

If you don't want to change the way the script works, quote everything properly:

```
ann="<?php echo '<h2>'.views_get_view('frprev_ann')->get_title().'</h2>'; echo views_embed_view('frprev_ann'); ?>"
col1content=$(echo "$ann" | sed 's/[\\\/&]/\\&/g')
sed -i "s/r${rownum}c1content/${col1content}/g" templates/page--front.tpl.php
```

Alternatively, use awk or perl, which can read an environment variable from within the script.

```
ann="<?php echo '<h2>'.views_get_view('frprev_ann')->get_title().'</h2>'; echo views_embed_view('frprev_ann'); ?>"
awk -v ann="$ann" -v rownum="$rownum" '
    BEGIN {pattern = "r" rownum "c1content"; }
    1 {gsub(pattern, ann); print}
' templates/page--front.tpl.php >templates/page--front.tpl.php.new
mv templates/page--front.tpl.php.new templates/page--front.tpl
```